# Java SQLData - Cast to user object with a list/array?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, types, mapping

I'm learning on how to use SQLData and having an issue with casting back to my object.

My Oracle Types looks something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE activities_t AS OBJECT
(
   list   activity_list_t;
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE activity_list_t AS TABLE OF activity_t;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE activity_t AS OBJECT
(
   startDate  DATE;
   endDate    DATE;
);
```

And my Java looks like this:

```
public class Activities implements SQLData {
    private String sqlType = "ACTIVITIES_T";
    List<Activity> list;

    // must have default ctor!
    public Activities() {
    }

    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException
    { 
        return sqlType; 
    }

    public List getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException 
    {
        Array a = stream.readArray();
        // :(
    }

    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException 
    {
        // stream.writeArray(this.list);
    }
}
```

I've tried a few things in readSQL but I am not having much success - what am I missing?

I am calling a PLSQL stored procedure which has an OUT parameter of "activities_t" using JDBC:

```
Map map = connection.getTypeMap();
map.put("ACTIVITIES_T", Class.forName("Activities"));
connection.setTypeMap(map);

callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call GET_ACTIVITIES(?)}");
callableStatement.execute();
```

Thanks!
Steve

(most of the above is from memory as the code is at work...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to add a type mapping for the type `ACTIVITY_T` as well as the one for `ACTIVITIES_T`.  It's not clear from your question whether you've already done this.

Let's assume you've done this and created a class called `Activity` which implements `SQLData` as well.  Once you've done that, the following should suffice to read the activity list within `Activities`:

```
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        Array array = stream.readArray();
        this.list = new ArrayList<Activity>();
        for (Object obj : (Object[])array.getArray()) {
            list.add((Activity)obj);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, once I worked out I was missing the other type mapping I ended up with something similar :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what about writeSQL implementation? I can't find a proper way to convert List to java.sql.Array.

Comment: @DmitryAvgustis: how about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439543)?

Answer (score 3):

**Tips:**

- JDBC APIs are case-sensitive with regard to type names; you will see a `Unable to resolve type` error if your type name does not exactly match. Oracle will uppercase your type name unless you double-quoted the name in its create statement.
- You may need to specify `SCHEMA.TYPE_NAME` if the type isn't in your default schema.
- Remember to `grant execute` on types if the user you are connecting with is not the owner.
  If you have execute on the package, but not the type, `getArray()` will throw an exception when it tries to look for type metadata.

**getArray()**

My solution is essentially the same as Luke's. However, I needed to provide a type mapping when getting the array: `array.getArray(typeMap)`
You can also set a default type map on the Connection, but this didn't work for me.

When calling `getArray()` you get an array of the object type, i.e. the `SQLData` implementation you created that represents `activity_t`

Here is a generic function you might find useful:

```
public static <T> List<T> listFromArray(Array array, Class<T> typeClass) throws SQLException {
    if (array == null) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    // Java does not allow casting Object[] to T[]
    final Object[] objectArray = (Object[]) array.getArray(getTypeMap());
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(objectArray.length);
    for (Object o : objectArray) {
        list.add(typeClass.cast(o));
    }
    return list;
}
```

**writeArray()**

Figuring out how to write an array was frustrating, Oracle APIs require a Connection to create an Array, but you don't have an obvious Connection in the context of `writeSQL(SQLOutput sqlOutput)`. Fortunately, [this blog](http://www.pspinksoftware.com/apps/blog/show/44088602-outputting-a-java-sql-array-within-sqldata-writesql-) has a trick/hack to get the `OracleConnection`, which I've used here.

When you create an array with `createOracleArray()` you **specify the list type** for the type name, NOT the object type. i.e. `activity_list_t`

Here's a generic function for writing arrays. In your case, `listType` would be `"activity_list_t"` and you would pass in a `List<Activity>`

```
public static <T> void writeArrayFromList(SQLOutput sqlOutput, String listType, @Nullable List<T> list) throws SQLException {
    final OracleSQLOutput out = (OracleSQLOutput) sqlOutput;
    OracleConnection conn = (OracleConnection) out.getSTRUCT().getJavaSqlConnection();
    conn.setTypeMap(getTypeMap());  // not needed?
    if (list == null) {
        list = Collections.emptyList();
    }
    final Array array = conn.createOracleArray(listType, list.toArray());
    out.writeArray(array);
}
```

Note: at one point I thought `setTypeMap` was required, but now when I remove that line my code still works, so I'm not sure if it's necessary.

Comment: Oracle is case sensitive and does not upper-case everything - the default behaviour is to convert all unquoted identifiers to upper case (so it appears to be case insensitive) but you can suppress that behaviour using double quotes around the identifiers and it will respect the case sensitivity of the identifiers.

Comment: Edited to clarify. If I lowercase a type name, I get this error
```error code [17060]; Fail to construct descriptor: Unable to resolve type "MYSCHEMA.mytype"; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Fail to construct descriptor: Unable to resolve type "MYSCHEMA.mytype```

Comment: If you do `CREATE TYPE MYSCHEMA."mytype" IS ...` in Oracle then you will get a type where the type's identifier is case-sensitive (and lower case). If you do `CREATE TYPE MYSCHEMA.mytype IS ...`(without the quotes) then you will get a type where the type's identifier is `MYTYPE` (in upper-case) as Oracle will, behind the scenes, convert unquoted identifiers to upper case. Your opening line "Even though Oracle is case-insensitive" is incorrect - Oracle is case sensitive when you use quoted identifiers and when you don't use quoted identifiers it will convert everything to upper case.