# Passing Array of string to pl/sql function from java

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I am trying to pass array of values from java to PL/SQL function. I am trying as below,

```
String[] array = {"70" , "2" , "4" , "9" , "329" , "13" , "49" , "33"};
Connection cnn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
 ArrayDescriptor descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("VLIST", cnn);
ARRAY array_to_pass = new ARRAY(descriptor, cnn,array);
 OracleCallableStatement pstmt = (OracleCallableStatement) cnn.prepareCall("{? = call  GETSRCHLST2(?)}");
pstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
 pstmt.setArray(2, array_to_pass);
pstmt.execute();
String output = pstmt.getString(1);
out.println(output+"\n"+ " "+array_to_pass.length());
```

Here in the function call no content of array is getting passed but array_to_pass.length() is 8.

Oracle procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EDR.GETSRCHLST2(VV VLIST) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

BN NUMBER;
STRS VARCHAR2(9000):='start';
HH varchar2(30);

BEGIN

STRS:=STRS || '- LIST COUNT: '||VV.COUNT||' - ';
BN:=VV.FIRST;

WHILE BN IS NOT NULL
LOOP

   HH:=VV(BN);
   STRS:=STRS||HH||' , ';
   BN := VV.NEXT(BN);   

END LOOP;

RETURN STRS;

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN RETURN 'SOME ERROR'||SQLERRM;
end;
```

Can anyone tell me, where i am going wrong?

Comment: See that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198856/pass-array-to-oracle-procedure

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had tried this one but no use.

Comment: Hi, Can you please post your **VLIST** type declaration or DDL?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I found the solution here. Changed VLIST type from VARCHAR to NVARCHAR.

Comment: @safoorasafu Ok then please provide your **VLIST** DDL and answer the question below, May be it helps someone someday, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope it may help those who is in search of same solution.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE DR.VLIST AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50)
```

But the value passed from java in array will not match VARCHAR instead it expects NVARCHAR. So made a slight changes as ,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE DR.VLIST AS TABLE OF NVARCHAR2(50)
```

it solved my the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`oracle.sql.ARRAY` is deprecated. Instead, you can call [OracleConnection.createOracleArray(String arrayTypeName, Object elements)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#createOracleArray_java_lang_String__java_lang_Object_)
Note that `arrayTypeName` should be the *table of* type and `elements` should be your Java array `T[]` where `T` corresponds to the type that `arrayTypeName` is a list of. (this can be a class implementing `SQLData`)

For more information, you might find my [my answer on getArray() and writeArray()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45867910/197733) useful.